# Logging not writing variable values but everything else

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I can successfully write to my log file using `logging.info('text')`.

However, calling upon all `self.` variables within all of my classes does **not** write to the log file.

Yet, `print()` displays their values to console.

For example: `logging.info('__getitem__')` appears in log files ok; but not any variable.

```py
import logging

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='ontology_tagger.log', level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info('Started')
    run_some_code()
    logging.info('Finished')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Further down the line of invocations:

```py
logging.info('__getitem__') # CHECK LOG FILE BELOW
y = 100
print(y)
logging.info('y = ', y)
```

Log File:

```
INFO:root:Started
INFO:root:__getitem__
INFO:root:Finished
```

Console | `print(y)`:

```
100
```

Comment: The duplicate is about logging _two_ values but it certainly also reveals how to log just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging does not allow you to concatenate a string literal with a variable directly.

So, instead of:

```py
logging.info('y =', y)
```

use the formatting mechanism provided by `logging`; the first argument is a format string, and then you can pass in as many additional arguments as it has placeholders.

```py
logging.info('y = %i', y)
```

Of course, you can also arrange your code so that it only passes in a single string, but this tends to be less efficient (f-strings, explicit `format`, or explicit string formatting with the `%` operator concatenates the strings, which is slightly inefficient, and completely wasteful if the string you hssemble is not actually getting logged anywhere because you turned off logging for this level).

```py
logging.info(f'y = {y}')
```

Yet anothe (crude) alternative:

```py
logging.info('y =')
logging.info(y)
```

Comment: Sorry, I've since tried this an the original problem occurs where the value of a variable isn't shown. So I wouldn't advise this @tripleee

Comment: Since my comment was deleted, let me reiterate: The correct way to do this is to use the formatting facility of `logging` which specifically exists to avoid unnecessarily concatenating values which might end up not being logged at all. `logging.info('y = %i', y)` where the format code `%i` tells `logging` that there is another argument and how to format it if it is to be logged.

Comment: Mightn't work for mine and others then, if we are using a different version of `Python` or `logging`? Idk. Your approach would be the preferred option, both in terms of minimal code and performance. Thank you. @tripleee

Comment: Then your Python is really old; this has been there at least since 2.7: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug

Comment: Hmm, I am on `Python 3.6.1`. Maybe I just didn't implement your coded solution correctly. Feel free to edit my answer to include yours, because I would otherwise prefer your solution.

Comment: Not a fan of big edits; feel free to roll back if you think it's too intrusive.